# Spring request parameter unique within call

Tags: spring-mvc, parameters

**Massive EDIT**

Let's say I have two differents controllers. One that renders the View and one that renders the `<jsp:include>` tags.

The `ViewController` :

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {
    @Resource
    private VehicleCatalogAPIService vehicleCatalogAPIService;

    @RequestMapping("/en/new/{organizationUnitId}")
    public String view(ModelMap modelMap, Locale locale,
                       @PathVariable Integer organizationUnitId,) {

        Vehicles vehicles = vehicleCatalogAPIService.getVehicule(organizationUnitId);

        modelMap.put("vehicles", vehicles);

        return "/catalog/" + view;
    }
}
```

The `IncludeController`:

```
@Controller
public class IncludeController{

    @Resource
    VehicleCatalogAPIService vehicleCatalogAPIService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/fragment/test", produces = "text/html")
    public String test(ModelMap modelMap,
                       @RequestParam("view") String view,
                       @RequestParam("test") String test,
                       @RequestParam("vehicleId") String vehicleId,
                       Locale locale) {
        Vehicle particularVehicle = vehicleCatalogAPIService.get(vehicleId);

        modelMap.put("vehicle", vehicle);

        return "/catalog/vehicle/fragments/" + view;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/fragment/test2", produces = "text/html")
    public String test(ModelMap modelMap,
                       @RequestParam("test") String test,
                       @RequestParam("view") String view,
                       Locale locale) {

        return "/catalog/vehicle/fragments/" + view;
    }
}
```

I hit the page in the browser : http://example.com/en/new

The ViewController is called and returns the the jsp page that has to be rendered, in this case `/catalog/listing.jsp`. The JSP looks like this :

```
<jsp:useBean id="vehicles" type="java.util.List<com.sm360.auto.webauto.webapplib.bean.display.VehicleDisplayBean>" scope="request"/>

<h1> LISTING JSP </h1>
<div>
    <c:forEach items="${vehicles}" var="vehicle" begin="${k.index}" end="${k.index + k.step-1}">
        <div class="c-item-out">
            <content:sheet-new-vehicule vehicle="${vehicle}" isCompact="true" hasCompared="true" />
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</div>

<jsp:include page="/fragment/test">
    <jsp:param name="view" value="view1"/>
    <jsp:param name="vehicle1" value="vehicle1"/>
    <jsp:param name="test" value="test1"/>
</jsp:include>
```

That include now calls the IncludeController with 3 parameters : view, vehicleId and test. The proper method is invoked and the correct view is returned (view1).

The view1 contains another include :

```
<jsp:useBean id="vehicle" type="com.sm360.auto.webauto.webapplib.bean.display.VehicleDisplayBean" scope="request"/>

<h1> view 1 </h1>
<div>
    <h2>${vehicle.name}
</div>

<jsp:include page="/fragment/test2">
    <jsp:param name="view" value="view2"/>
    <jsp:param name="test" value="test2"/>
</jsp:include>
```

In that second call, the view parameter will be "view2,view1" and the test parameter will be "test2, test1".

I would like that second include to have its own values of the parameters it passes to the controller, not a merge from the other call.

EDIT :

[image: Spring MVC Diagram]

Following this diagram, when a `<jsp:include>` is met during the rendering of the view, does the process return to the Front Controller and re-Delegate the request to the Controller specified in the `include` tag with the same request with updated parameters?

Is it possible to have a new set of fresh parameters?

Comment: Could you paste the controller method in question?

Comment: Can you show what you mean by _That view contains another call to the same or another controller_? Is there a link, a form submit?

Comment: Theres is a `<jsp:include>`tag in that view. It calls the given url and render the output where it is placed.

Answer (score 0):

A long shot: could you just [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html?is-external=true#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) the `view` entry from the [model](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html) before setting the next? I'm having [a common Spring controller method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller) in mind, please post your code for clarification.

```
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
public String helloWorld(Model model) {
    model.remove("view");
    model.addAttribute("view", "foobar");
    return "helloWorld";
}
```

Comment: I thought of this, but I need a more generic solution as the problem will happens with other parameters as well not only the "view" parameter like my example. I've updated with some code and another example.

Comment: What about clearing the model with `modelMap.clear()`? I guess that would be too generic (I only used it before redirects). If so, you really are looking for a way to **replace** the values, not removing them. How are you calling a second time from the view, where the values get appended instead of replaced? Do you generate a `<a>` tag or call it in Java from the JSP?

Comment: I'll update my question, I think my approach was wrong here. That appending behavior is useful in some situation.